# Get variable and page fragment using Jquery .load() function

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, web2py

I am currently using Jquery's .load() function to insert a page fragment asynchronously. In the URL that I am loading the page fragment from, I also set a Javascript global variable value (in the script tag).

```
var loaded_variable = 'value1'
```

Is there a way I can use the .load() function to insert the page fragment AND retrieve the value of `loaded_variable`, something like the following code:

```
    function loadProducts(url) {
                 $('#mainplace').load(url + ' #submain', function() { 
                       current_variable = loaded_variable;
                 });
    }
```

I am aware that script blocks are used when a selector expression is appended to the URL, so if the .load() function won't work, I'm open to other Jquery functions that can accomplish this.

Extra Info: The URL that I am loading from is written in HTML and Python (Web2py); the same Python variables are used to render the page fragment and set the `loaded_variable` value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to both fetch a fragment from a page and execute a script on it, you'll need a different approach. This is a bit hacky, but works.

```
$.ajax({url: 'fetch_page.html', dataType: 'text'}).done(function(html) {
    var dom = $('<html />').prop('innerHTML', html);
    $('body').append(dom.find('body p'));
    $('head').append(dom.find('script'));
});
```

That fetches a `p` tag from our fetched pages and inserts it into the `body` of the parent page. It also executes any scripts in the fetched page.

If you're wondering about the `prop('innerHTML...` bit, that's because if I'd used jQuery's `.html()` method, it sanitises the input string and so we don't get the result we want.

My first thought was a document fragment, but you can't insert an HTML string into a doc frag - you have to append via DOM methods. Even then in this case it wouldn't really offer any saving over simply using an element to parse the dom (`dom`) as I have.

Bit hacky, as I say, but works.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Could you explain the 2nd line of your code? I don't understand what the selector `$('<html />')` is referring to

Comment: I've used your response, but to execute the Javascript I use `scripter = dom.find('script').text(); eval(scripter);` as opposed to the append method, which was not working.

Comment: Sorry - I've only just seen these comments. The line you question creates a new `html` element and uses it to house the HTML you're loading. Crucially, this converts it to a DOM and therefore makes it traversable.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have a similar question. I have create a page that will hold a newsletter sign up. I want to load this page at the bottom of every blog post on my site. I don't want it in the footer because it is specific to my blog page and I want the ability to edit it without having to edit every blog post.

I created this page with the url /blog-newsletter-form which includes some code from an Email CRM.

I then added a div with a "blog-newsletter-form" class at the end of my blog posts and put the following in the page header to load the content from the first page section inside my blog posts.

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('.blog-newsletter-form').load("/blog-newsletter-signup #page .page-section:nth-of-type(1) .content");
});
```

This worked great except.. the load function is stripping the script from the newsletter page which is required for my newsletter form to work.

How do I load a page fragment but also keep the script for the newsletter. I tried using your sample code above and couldn't get it to work.